# Is there a way to freeze a cloth with a shape key?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, cloth-simulation

I created a curtain today using a CG Cookie tut that used shape keys, but when I went to apply it an error message comes up saying it can't be applied with shape keys, so my question is: is there another way to freeze a cloth simulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After enabling cloth, look under the modifier stack, there is a specific button there...

[image]

Comment: I did try that and it seemed to reset my animation. I'll give it another go though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After you apply the shape key in the Modifiers, locate the "Shape Keys" and you'll find a new "Cloth" shape key:

[image: Cloth added to shape keys]

Just click on "Cloth" and change the "Value" slider from 0 to 1.0 in order to make the cloth deformation visible:

[image: Shape Key value increased to 1.0]

Now your cloth should be visible in the 3D viewport.