# How can I bring back cloth simulation to original state?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am attaching here the screenshots.I can share the blend file if needed.
When the small sphere hits the large transparent sphere the cloth simulation gets activated. But when the small sphere leaves the surface back the large sphere is not coming back to its original state. Is there any way to do that?

Also Is there any method to apply cloth simulation only to the position where the small sphere hits? Because I need to create 4-5 small spheres with random movement inside the large sphere.

Thanks
Arun

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can create shapekeys out of the cloth simulation and animate those to set the deformation back and forth. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63419/is-there-a-way-to-freeze-a-cloth-with-a-shape-key

Comment: Read this link: https://odederell3d.blog/2018/08/17/blender-cloth-animation-to-shape-keys/

Comment: Yes !!! Thank you very much, It worked. Is there any method for the second issue, To make the cloth simulation work in the portion where the inner sphere hits? I made a vertex group with the vertices above but dont know where to connect it?